# Only logged to the first array

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a quiz HTML the thing is

I've set it for each wrong element to change the intertext to wrong

but it only changes the first element, eventought i set it to foreach, why is that?

```
const op1 = document.getElementById("op1")
const op2 = document.getElementById("op2")
const op3 = document.getElementById("op3")
const op4 = document.getElementById("op4")

    let origArray = [op1,op2,op3,op4];
                                    
var math = origArray[Math.floor(Math.random()* origArray.length)]
math.innerText = "Right"

function wrong(){
    var cloneArray = origArray.slice();
var i = math;

const something = cloneArray.splice(i,1);

something.forEach(elem => {
    elem.innerText = "Wrong"
    console.log(elem.id)
});
}

wrong()
```

Comment: you're only returning one item from your `splice()` call, so `something` only has a length of 1.

Comment: umm what should i do ?

Comment: inst that "something" return every element except the "math" ?

Comment: `splice()` returns the deleted element/s not the remaining array, so you should call `forEach()` on `cloneArray` after the splice call.

Comment: im sorry but my english is bad
can you give me example of that ?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): _"Return value: An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
const op1 = document.getElementById("op1")
const op2 = document.getElementById("op2")
const op3 = document.getElementById("op3")
const op4 = document.getElementById("op4")

    let origArray = [op1,op2,op3,op4];
var rightIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* origArray.length);                                    
var math = origArray[rightIndex];
math.innerText = "Right"

function wrong(){
    var cloneArray = origArray.slice();
var i = rightIndex;

cloneArray.splice(i,1);

cloneArray.forEach(elem => {
    elem.innerText = "Wrong"
    console.log(elem.id)
});
}

wrong()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not logging is because it is not iterating through all of the elements but only the *one* returned by splice.

Below is a better way(imo) to do what you seek to do:

```
//Get option DOM-element references
const op1 = document.getElementById("op1");
const op2 = document.getElementById("op2");
const op3 = document.getElementById("op3");
const op4 = document.getElementById("op4");

//Make an array with all the listed options
let originalArray= [op1,op2,op3,op4];

//Save a random element "math" as the right answer, and set it's inner text to "Right"                                     
var correctArrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* originalArray.length);
originalArray[correctArrayIndex].innerText = "Right";
//This functions returns a cloned array of the original array with the correct text
function returnClonedArrayWithWrong(inputArray, correctIndex){
    var clonedArray = inputArray.splice();
    for(var i = 0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
        if(i != correctIndex){
            clonedArray[i].innerText = "Wrong";
        }else{
            clonedArray[i].innerText = "Right";
        }
        console.log("Element ID: "+ clonedArray[i].id); // For logging the output
    }
    return clonedArray;
}
var clonedArrayFilled = returnClonedArrayWithWrong(originalArray, correctArrayIndex);
```